# How to fetch the text attribute of an object using index in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
object.option[index].title=object.option[index].text
```

This is in javaScript and needs to be converted to jquery. Please help me.

Comment: this is a task and not a question, therefor off topic

Comment: please first try to find out the solution in google with some research then after come here and ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that title and text are properties of the respective elements try this:

```
$('#elem').attr('title', $('#other-elem').attr('text'));
```

## elem is the element you are changing the title of, #other-elem is the element with the text you are assigning to #elem.